# how to take a screenshot of a specific LinearLayout?

Tags: android

I need to take a screenshot of a specific linearlayout using

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) switchCenter.getChildAt(0);

    ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    Bitmap bm = switchCenter.getDrawingCache();

    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);

    BitHistoryList.add(bm);
```

But my program stops responding... any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: any error messages from the logcat?

Comment: Can you post your logs? It could be a memory issue. What device are you testing on?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
        .....
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        view.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
        ......
```